# Reasons against Turing machines in proof complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory

Turing machines were very successful in computability theory where Turing used them to resolve the Halting problem. His breakthrough led to proving that many other problems are algorithmicly undecidable. Key attribute of Turing machines is their infinite memory. However, natural complexity problems are combinatorial in nature and require finite memory and time.

In complexity theory, the infiniteness of memory has been addressed by forcing artificial bounds. We did not yet succeed in finding the right *natural* model of computation for time-bounded computations that would lead to breakthroughs in major open problems of complexity theory. I am particularly interested in natural computation models for proof complexity which does not involve explicit resource bounds.

> Why Turing machines may not be the appropriate model to resolve the NP vs CoNP problem? Are there any *natural* combinatorial models?